# STintersects() to find the Intersection point

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, geospatial, spatial

I have two sql server `geometry`-ies which I am using to check if they intersect. If they do I need the intersection point.

Currently I can get only Boolean output where if it `intersects = 1` and if it does not intersect it will give `=0` . Is there any way I can find the intersection of two shapes in `geometry`?

---

***Update*** this question led to my next question concerning how can one check if a point (lat/long) exists in a region which has 4000 points (lat/long). Can one use stcontains or stintersects on geography?

[sql - STContains on Geography column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13484636/stcontains-on-geography-column)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
DECLARE @line1 GEOMETRY = geometry::STGeomFromText('LINESTRING(0 0, 1 1)', 0)
DECLARE @line2 GEOMETRY = geometry::STGeomFromText('LINESTRING(1 0, 0 1)', 0)

SELECT  @line1.STIntersection(@line2).ToString()
```

Comment: Any idea how can i check if my 1 point (lat/long) exists in a region which has 4000 points (lat/long). I want to use stcontains or stintersects on geography

Comment: @ace_mccloud: please post it as another question with a more detailed setup.

Comment: Hey there, Here is the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13484636/stcontains-on-geography-column