# Find length of geometry line after it intersects with geometry polygon using STIntersect

Tags: sql-server, geometry, spatial, intersect

```
SQL SERVER 2012
```

I need to find the length of the geometry of a line after I use `STIntersect` to intersect lines against polygon geometry.
For instance, I have a line that is 7731 meters long but then I `STIntersect` it against a set of polygons, I need to find what the length of the line is in each of the polygons.

Output table would look like

```
ReferenceID    PolygonID   LineID   Length
12324          3234        24661    1635
12325          3233        24652     663
12326          3236        24653     256
12327          3365        24634     165
```

Currently using this but not able to return geometry nor the length

```
insert [VMS_OBS_LINES_INTERSECT] (CA_Reference_Key, STAT_AREA,WATERS,GNMFSAREA, Grid_ID, Length)select l.CA_Reference_Key,g.stat_area,g.waters, g.GNMFSAREA , g.Grid_ID, g.shape.STIntersection(l.shape).STLength()
FROM GRID_AREA_SQL g, VMS_OBS_COMBINE_LINES_AI l
WHERE g.shape.STIntersects(l.shape) = 1;
```

Comment: Does this answer your question?
<http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13259215/stintersects-to-find-the-intersection-point>

Answer (score 4):

```
declare @g geometry, @l geometry;

select @g = geometry::STGeomFromText('POLYGON ((0 0, 10 0, 10 10, 0 10, 0 0))', 0), --10x10 box
       @l = geometry::STGeomFromText('LINESTRING( -10 -10 , 20 20 )', 0); --a line that will go through the corners of the box

select @g.STIntersection(@l).STLength();
```